# [C++]Importing text file - Problems with getline()

Tags: c++, file, text, import

I've been having trouble with reading text files in c++, particularly when assigning a line to a variable.

I have the following code:

```
ifstream fx;
fx.open(nomeFich);
if(!fx)
{cout << "FX. nao existe!" <<endl;}
string linha="";;
int pos, inic;

while(!fx.eof())
{
    getline(fx,linha);

    if(linha.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << linha << endl;
        inic=0;
        pos=0;
        pos=linha.find(",",inic);
        cout << pos << endl;
        string nomeL1(linha.substr(inic,pos));
        cout << "atribuiu 1" << endl;
        inic=pos;

        cout <<"inic: " << inic << "      pos:" << pos <<endl;

        pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        string nomeL2(linha.substr(inic,pos));
        cout << "atribuiu 2" << endl;
        inic=pos;

        cout <<"inic: " << inic << "      pos:" << pos <<endl;

        pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        cout << "atribuiu 3" << endl;
        string dist(linha.substr(inic,pos));
```

When it does the `cout << linha << endl;` it returns something like :

> = = == = = = = == = = = = = = = == = = = = == = = = = =

I've googled it quite a lot and can't find an answer.
I'm new to C++ so don't bash too much xD

Comment: Why not using `fx.getline()`?

Comment: like
    linha=fx.getline();?
It gives an error..

Comment: `fx >> linha;` while we're at it.

Comment: You will process one too many lines as eof won't be set until you read past the end of the file.  Use `while( getline( fx, linha ) ) { }`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this:

```
while(!fx.eof())
{
    getline(fx,linha);   // Here you have to check if getline() actually succeded
                         // before you do any further processing.
                         // You could add if (!fx) { break;}

    // STUFF;
}
```

But the better design is:

```
while(getline(fx,linha))  // If the read works then enter the loop otherwise don't
{
    // STUFF
}
```

You are failing to move past the comma:

```
inic=pos;                  // pos is the position of the last ',' or std::string::npos
pos=linha.find(',',inic);  // So here pos will be the same as last time.
                           // As you start searching from a position that has a comma.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifstream` has a `getline` function, it accepts a `char*` as the first parameter and the maximum length as the second.

`ifstream` also has `operator>>` which you should be using for input, but it will read till whitespace, which is not what you want.

`::getline` that you're using should also work, but that's assuming that the stream is OK, which as mentioned before, you don't check correctly. You should be checking for errors after calling it, because if you reach EOF or there's an error, you won't know until the whole loop is done.

Also, what's in the file? Maybe what you're getting is the correct result?

Comment: I don't want to use the getline associated to char because i don't exactly now the length of the line.

I've a txt file with the following:

Lisboa,Porto,300
Faro,Porto,600
Porto,Faro,600
Maia,Porto,50
Porto,Covilha,150

The idea is to separate the line in three string variables using the commas as a separator.

Tried what Ed S. as well as little adv sugested and had no success, still the same..

Comment: How do I check for erros calling it?

Comment: @NunoNeto It returns the reference to the stream, so you can just use `!` on the return value.